# Cumulative distribution function for the product of two random variables

Tags: random-variable, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function

Given two random variables $x, y$, each with the probability distribution functions $p_x(x)$, $p_y(y)$, then if $z = xy$, then $p_z(z) = \int p_x(x)p_y(z/x)\frac{1}{|x|}dx $.

Is there a similar proof that gives the cumulative distribution for $z$ given the cumulative distribution functions for $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Ordinarily, a "probability distribution function" is another term for CDF.  Evidently you are referring to probability *density* functions.